# How bring Windows 7 backup catalog into sync with reality?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I recently replaced a 1TB hard drive I use for storing Windows 7 backups with a 3TB drive. To do this, I copied all the files from the old drive to the new drive, removed the old drive, then assigned the same drive letter and drive name to the new drive that I'd used with the old drive. Windows 7 backup seems to run like it used to, but when I view the backup sets I have (e.g., via Manage Space>View backups...", they all have the same date: "4/4/2015 to 4/4/2015". That's the date I replaced the drive. If I look on the drive itself, I see older backup sets, with names such as "Backup Set 2015-02-07 00005", and though Windows Explorer lists 4/4/2015 in the "Date Modified" column for those folders, pushing down to files with names like "Backup files 1.zip" shows a modification date of 2/7/2015.

My guess is that Windows Backup is showing the wrong dates for the backup sets, because its catalog files went out of sync with the contents of the disk when I copied the files from the old drive to the new drive. How can I get Windows Backup to show accurate information on the backup sets I have on disk?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about bringing the catalog file in sync but if possible try using robocopy to copy the old backups from the 1TB drive to the 3TB drive again. If I'm not mistake either must be ran as administrator.
For robocopy:

```
robocopy 1TB\sourcedir 3TB\destdir /copyall /E
```

This will copy all the files from the old hdd to the new one and keep all the attributes for the files (timestamps, creator, etc) The /copyall options is what retains the attributes for the files while the /E option will copy the subdirectories as well.

This will I think make the windows backup program show everything with the correct dates.